# socket io send message to a user in a room

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chatroom

I am using nodejs and socketio. I made a private chat app which sends message to selected user.

My current code is :

```
          chat_room.sockets.socket(user).emit(
                'chat', 
                { 
                    message : message,
                    from : sockets[socket.id].username
                }
            );
```

Now I created rooms and I want to send message to a user of a specific room.

I tried below code but not working

```
socket.get('room', function(err, room) {
         chat_room.sockets.socket(room)(user).emit(
                'chat', 
                { 
                    message : message,
                    from : sockets[socket.id].username
                }
            );

});
```

Its wrong and it gave me an error :

> C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\joomla-chat\app.js:62
>                 chat_room.sockets.socket(room)(user).emit(
>                                               ^ TypeError: object is not a function
>       at chat_room.sockets.on.socket.on.socketID (C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\joomla-chat\app.js:62:45)
>       at Client.get (C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\joomla-chat\node_modules\socket.io\lib\stores\memory.js:86:3)
>       at Socket.get (C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\joomla-chat\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:258:14)
>       at Socket.chat_room.sockets.on.socket.on.socketID (C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\joomla-chat\app.js:48:16)
>       at Socket.EventEmitter.emit [as $emit] (events.js:96:17)
>       at SocketNamespace.handlePacket (C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\joomla-chat\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:335:22)
>       at Manager.onClientMessage (C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\joomla-chat\node_modules\socket.io\lib\manager.js:487:38)
>       at WebSocket.Transport.onMessage (C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\joomla-chat\node_modules\socket.io\lib\transport.js:387:20)
>       at Parser. (C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\joomla-chat\node_modules\socket.io\lib\transports\websocket\hybi-16.js:39:10)
>       at Parser.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)

How can I send message to a specific user of a room

-------------------------------EDIT----------------------------
So if I do :

```
socket.get('room', function(err, room) {
              chat_room.sockets.socket(user).emit(
                    'chat', 
                    { 
                        message : message,
                        from : sockets[socket.id].username
                    }
                );

        });
```

Then this will fire the message to Mr.X to ABC room

Am I right?

Comment: What is the variable 'user'? How you contact them will depend on what information you have (for example, if you have their socket.id, it will just be a simple socket.emit)

Comment: its socket ID of the person to whom the message to be delivered

Comment: In that case you simply need to do a socket.emit to that user; it doesn't matter that they are in a room, traditional emits will still work the same

Comment: Not exactly; I'll post an answer as to what you should do...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regardless of whether or not the user you want to contact is in a room, the easiest way to contact them, provided you have the proper identifying information, is still just a simple socket.emit().

You stated that you already have their socket.id; if so, then getting their socket object is as simple as: `io.sockets.sockets[socket.id]`.

To send a message you can then say: `io.sockets.sockets[socket.id].emit('identifier', data);`

That should answer your question, although these are two additional things you may find helpful:

-To broadcast to the entire room you are focusing on: `io.sockets.in('room').emit('event_name', data)`

-There is a very rich amount of information regarding both rooms and connected sockets stored within io.sockets. I strongly recommend that you put a `console.log(io.sockets);` in the beginning of your code and inspect the object closely to see what else you can access.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks now I am clear that if I have socket ID of the opposite user then it doesn't matter that whether he is in this room or any other room cause socket ID will help him to trigger the message